# Help with Java program (Swing + database)

Tags: java, database, file, swing, user-interface

Could somebody give me a suggestion on how to simply and effectively make GUI representation of directories which are contained inside the database. Now, getting information using SQL queries is one thing. I can do that. 
In fact using separate small examples I can put a file inside the database along with his information and I can get the file out of the database. The thing is I was just doing this without GUI, just to test does it work.

Now I need a GUI of this and I really don't know where to start. DO I use JTable, JList or something third? Also, I think I need an multidimensional array because I have, for example, id of a file, name_of_file and size.

So I need different types to put them in: int, String and int.
Also, I need to obviously hide the id of a file from the user yet keep it at the same time in order to be able to reference it.

How do I hide it in a GUI component?

So, let's say that I have a database table for files with these columns:
id, name, size, binary_of_file.

My real table has a bit more of columns like, id of a parent directory, id of a owner, etc. but for now this is not important.

So, I tell database to give me all info about the file (except it's binary because I just want to list the files):

```
...
ResultSet rs = statementObject.executeQuery("SELECT id, name, size FROM Files;");
while(rs.next()){
    //Where do I store the values in? Which GUI component and how?
...
```

I guess I need an JPanel that will contain this component that will show my files from the database. What component? Please help!

Comment: See [How to Use Tables](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html).

Comment: @trashgod:  After carefully reviewing the answers and comments to this question, I am beginning to suspect the OP is not following links.  :-(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you want to use a JTable, it has a [TableModel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html) interface that you can implement to adapt to your resultset.

---

Also follow the link at the top of the docs. to *Creating a Table Model*.

Comment: For example, [`JDBCAdapter`](http://www.di.unito.it/~giovanna/DIDATTICA/aa0405/SpDB-L/esercizi/8-gui/TableExample/src/JDBCAdapter.java).

Comment: Can JTable show certain information like name, size etc. and hide other like id that corresponds to the file in database?

Comment: *"Can JTable show certain information ...and hide other"* Yes.  It depends on the [TableModel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html) as to what is and is not included.  As I keep saying:- *"See the linked code (in my answer) for an example."*  Have you tried that code yet?  Have you looked at how it works?

Comment: @Tom:  I edited your answer to include a link to TableModel (since I noticed I was just repeating what you'd already said).  But then I got carried away and added the text after the line.  Please review it and remove anything you feel is not appropriate.

Comment: Will try it with TableModel. I'm not exactly familiar with all this new information like models etc. so it will take time I think.

Comment: Models underly much of [Swing Architecture](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/architecture/), so it's time well spent.

Comment: Just to report: I managed to put the query result into my JTable using AbstractTableModel. I just had to add validate() as well since sometimes my table woudn't just show up. Sorry that it took so long to respond everybody but my guess is we're in different timezones (I'm somewhere in between Andrew and Tom) and when I got your answers it was pretty late so I went to bed. Tom and Andrew, thank you both!

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps a combined `JList`/`JTable` component would fit this need.

[image]

That is a screen shot of the GUI of [FileBro](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/4446/file-browser-gui).

My idea is that the `JTree` on the left would represent the 'directories' and table (names) of the DB.  The `JTable` on the right would contain the data of the selected table.  Change the `Locate Open Edit Print` buttons for `Create Update Delete` and the panel below that to show details of records, and it would be the start of a DB CRUD component.

Comment: Looks great but is JTree capable of showing database files or is it only able to "see" real files? How would one add information from the example SQL I posted?

Comment: A `JTree` can contain any objects.  What it looks like on-screen is all about the renderer.  See the linked code for an example.